# A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. ts(2556)

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error in `evt(...args);`

My code:

```
trigger<K extends keyof IEventMap>(
   eventName: K,
   ...args: Parameters<IEventMap[K]>
) {
   let group = this._getListeners(eventName);
   for (let evt of group) {
      evt(...args);
   }
}
```

Things I've tried but didn't work:

```
evt(...(args as const));
```

```
let tupple = [...args] as Parameters<IEventMap[K]>;
evt(...tupple);
```

```
let tupple  = [...args] as Parameters<IEventMap[K]>;
evt.apply(null, ...tupple);
```

Comment: What frameworks are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] the example to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  That means you should declare any private or third-party types or values that you're using... and preferably you'd remove them and replace with native types or values where possible.  That'll let everyone work from a common starting point.